# Disable the automatic Linkify of Webview

Tags: android, webview, linkify

I have a webview that I am creating.  It seems to automatically be linkifying numbers into tel: urls.  I didn't see a way to remove this ability (at least nothing similar to the way to enable it on a textview).

The code is pretty simple:

```
// populate the web view
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.app_info_webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
String url = APP_INFO_BODY_HTML + "?versionName=" + versionName;

webView.loadUrl(url);
```

I have a copyright notice at the bottom of the page, android is changing the 2011 into a clickable link that opens the dialer.  Also, the App version 1.0.0 opens in the dialer.

Is there a way to disable this functionality?

Update:  I just discovered that this seems device dependent...happens on the Droid X, but not a Samsung Captivate, not on Nexus S, and not the emulator.

Comment: you mentioned that using a textview would be fine too. here you find a link on how to add links to a textview http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to do that - rather ugly, two layered, but still a workaround.

You should

1. modify how the webview will handle the auto-linkifiable items
2. explicitly tell the loaded page not to apply styles and haptic feedback.

   ```
   mWebView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() {

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, final String url) {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

       //TODO analyse the uri here 
       //and exclude phone and email from triggering any action

       return false;
   }

   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, 
                                           String description, String failingUrl) {}

   public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {...}

   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {...}

   public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {...}
   });
   ```

   In the html specify the following meta tags inside the  tag:

   ```
   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
   <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no" />
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think there is a third format-detection type: <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />. Telephone-no stops automatic tel: links, email stops automatic mailto: links, and address stops geo: links. I can't find any official documentation on email or address. http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html only mentions telephone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised to see it is launching Dialer on selecting a number from your own WebView.

Unless, you override WebViewClient::shouldOverrideUrlLoading() and detect the url scheme has "tel" and start Dialer activity, it will never launch a Dialer from your WebView. Are you sure you are not handling tel: scheme in shouldOverrideUrlLoading()?

Answer (score -2):

You can find the code that do the real detection in `external`/`webkit`/`WebKit`/`android`/`nav`/`CacheBuilder.cpp` : `FindPartialNumber()` and so on.

You can disable it or change the logic as you like.