# Android WebView : disable geo: for addresses

Tags: android, webview, geo

In my Android application, I am using a WebView to render a list of locations. For some reason, when I click on a list item, it interprets it as a "geo:" address and opens the default browser to show the location. How can I configure the WebView to not interprete the location's addresses.

I don't want the "geo:" handling to swallow the "normal" list item touch event. If I tap carefully just on the location name then the "normal" list item touch event is fired. The WevView must interprete addresses automatically, since I don't add the "geo:" markup.

Sample content:

```
Southport Open Storage
3080 Promenade St, West Sacramento, CA 95691, USA
```

Sample content html:

```
<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
 <span class="location-address-name">D And L Heating And Air - HVAC Contractor</span><br>
 <span class="location-formatted-address">3236 Malcolm Island St, West Sacramento, CA 95691, USA</span>
</li>
```

Additional Info:

- Using jQueryMobile 1.0-b2 to for all UI components
- jQuery 1.6.2

[image]

I saw some posts about "geo:" but they mostly dealt with WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...) which seems no relevant to the above issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to add this to your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
```

See also this similar question:

- [Disable the automatic Linkify of Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472547/disable-the-automatic-linkify-of-webview)