# HTML Email iOS format-detection

Tags: html, html-email

I just found that there is a meta tag for removing the phone number as a link in HTML on iOS. Does this work with HTML emails?

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

But is there one for address and date as well? I have always been writing hacks to over come this but if it's a meta tag that is great! Does anyone know the syntax for address and date?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use:

- Date: [`<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249770/meta-format-detection-ios-for-dates)
- Address: [`<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053861/android-webview-disable-geo-for-addresses)
- Email: [`<meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798718/disabling-email-number-detection-in-android-webview)

Combining them:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">
```

Comment: Just a note - this only really works on native iOS and some Android email clients and not universally across different mobile email apps and mobile devices. For those you will still need to do the 'hacks' and workarounds.

Comment: Looks like this works for Windows phones also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: These don't work in the mail app in iOS 9 on the iPhone 6.

Comment: @crmpicco That's very possible. Email strips a lot of markup. That would sensibly include meta tags since they are relevant for the entire page. You would likely need to use some sort of hack for this (and many other things) to work properly in email.

Comment: @Anonymous It's quite frustrating as email is when these built-in features are the most intrusive, particularly on mobile.

Comment: Thank you! The fact that I can’t find this in [Supported Meta Tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.htm) baffles me.

Comment: Does this work in anything? Has anyone confirmed it? I can find no official documentation. The only thing that I can confirm works is telephone=no.

Comment: As of October 2016, this method didn't work on my iPhone 6 with iOs 10, where the emails have been sent using Outlook 2013. I also included the link styles in http://removebluelinks.com/, and tried with method #5 of https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices, but with no luck.

Answer (score 8):

I think its better to gather them in one meta tag :

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, email=no, address=no" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I've had luck with:

```
<style>
  a[href^="x-apple-data-detectors:"] {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: First time encountered ^= in css can you share exactly what is it doing?

Comment: @user471651 Like regex in js, `a[href^="x-apple-data-detectors:"]` means to match `a` tags whose `href` attribute value starts with `x-apple-data-detectors:`

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">
    <style type="text/css">
        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    123 Main Street<br/>
    Columbus, Ohio 43215
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've just encountered this issue with an email I was working on. Turns out, this effort is becoming almost futile because there are other devices other than IOS that are doing this type of detection and conversion. I wish browsers/devices gave the option to turn off this type of detection (if they don't), so us developers aren't spending considerable amounts of time researching a solution!

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered that format-detection doesn't work for Outlook.com, Office365, etc.

In my case I didn't want the auto styling OR functionality (of clicking to call or map an address) so I injected some hidden HTML to make it not look like an address.

Original:

```
<td>123 Main Street
<br/>Cambridge, MA 02138</td>
```

Updated:

```
<td>123 Main S<i class="hidden">-</i>treet
<br/>Cambridge, M<i class="hidden">-</i>A 02<i class="hidden">-</i>138</td>
```

With this added to your stylesheet:

```
.hidden { display:none; }
```

This was tested and works in the 50 or so email client previews offered by Email on Acid.

**NOTE:** you can't inline the display:none because Yahoo Mail doesn't support that and you'll end up with visible dashes in your address. You need to define a class.

**Removing display but keeping the functionality**

If you want to keep the Bing Maps pop up functionality you can customize the display by adding the class "outlookLink" to the element that contains the address. Source: https://litmus.com/community/discussions/4692-outlook-com-adding-links

So this:

```
<td>123 Main Street</td>
```

Becomes this:

```
<td class="outlookLink">123 Main Street</td>
```

with the following in your stylesheet:

```
.outlookLink span {
      color:#ffffff !important;
      border-bottom-width:0 !important;
      border-bottom-style:none !important;
}
```

Outlook.com wraps what it determines to be addresses or dates (for calendar entries) in a <span> with its own styling (blue link with dashed underline). This modifies the styling of those <span>s.

Answer (score 2):

A nice easy approach you could follow if you've got multiple rules you can combine them together as such:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no,date=no,address=no,email=no,url=no" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a standard meta tag, it just work for IOS.

See [Apple Developer Documention](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW1) to find your answer

Comment: Oddly enough, said documentation only mentions one format, even though there are at least four.

Answer (score -4):

untested but should work.

```
a[href^=date]{ color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;}
a[href^=telephone]{ color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;}
a[href^=address]{ color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;}
a[href^=email]{ color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;}
```